# Keep tmux title from `fg` to original jobname

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm using Eevee's [.zshrc](https://github.com/eevee/rc/blob/master/.zshrc)/[.tmux.conf](https://github.com/eevee/rc/blob/master/.tmux.conf).

When I'm running a vim session, and I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then `⚘ fg`, then it changes my tmux pane title to `fg`. I'd rather it change back to `vim whatever.txt`, or whatever I happened to be using.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `preexec()` function in your `.zshrc` to

```
function preexec {
  local fg_title
  if [[ $* == fg* ]]; then
     if [[ $* == *%* ]]; then
        fg_title=($(jobs ${${(z)1}[2]}))
     else
        fg_title=($(jobs %%))
     fi
     title "${fg_title[5,-1]}"
  else
     title $*
  fi
}
```

The code is surely not optimal, but it works if you use `fg` oder `fg %2` to put a process into foreground. However I could not figure out to make it work with `fg %vi` too.